# Есть ли возможность на питоне обработать адреса, которые записаны в различных форматах и построить карту?

Tags: python, анализ

Есть данные в которых перечислены адреса( могут встречаться опечатки) в различных форматах, где-то пишется г. Москва, ул......, где-то город Москва, улица...., а может г. МОсква, г.Зеленоград, ул...... Нужно все привести к одному формату и построить например в tableau карту. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Для разбора адресов можно попробовать `AddrExtractor` из библиотеки [Natasha](https://github.com/natasha/natasha), но, возможно, чуда не произойдёт и придётся допиливать результат регулярками.
- Для карт в питоне тоже есть очень много библиотек, сложно подсказать, какая вам подойдёт: `Altair`, `Plotly`, `Geopandas`, `Folium` и много-много других, можно погуглить по словам `python map library`.

Comment: помогите, пожалуйста, воспользовалась Наташей, получила ответ в виде Match(
    start=6,
    stop=112,
    fact=Addr(
        parts=[AddrPart(
             value='109469',
             type='индекс'
         ),
         AddrPart(
             value='Москва',
             type='город'
         ),
         AddrPart(
             value='Марьинский Парк',
             type='улица'
         ),
         AddrPart(
             value='21',
             type='дом'
          нужно собрать все в одну строку, не получается пока

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1236697/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova Там есть документация, примеры. Если не разберётесь, напишите, я попробую потом вспомнить как там что. Да, в том вопросе я по документации как-то разбирался, а сейчас уже не помню, надо заново вспоминать.

Comment: я нашла статьи на Хабре, что надо работать с spans, но всовременной версии нет natasha.markup   и поэтому след кусок кода не работает: matches = addr_extractor('ЮВАО, 109469, г Москва, Марьино, ул Марьинский Парк, д. 21,  2, Верхние Поля ул. (Марьинский парк ул.,д.21,кор.2)')
spans = [_.span for _ in matches]
facts = [_.fact.as_json for _ in matches]
show_markup('ЮВАО, 109469, г Москва, Марьино, ул Марьинский Парк, д. 21,  2, Верхние Поля ул. (Марьинский парк ул.,д.21,кор.2)', spans)
show_json(facts)