# Парсинг физических адресов

Tags: python, natasha

[image: Как записать распарсенный адрес в одну строку, то есть 123456, г Москва, улица Марьинский парк ,д.21,кор.2]

Как записать распарсенный адрес в одну строку, то есть 123456, г Москва, улица Марьинский парк ,д.21,кор.2

```
from natasha import (
    Segmenter,
    MorphVocab,
    
    NewsEmbedding,
    NewsMorphTagger,
    NewsSyntaxParser,
    NewsNERTagger,
    
    PER,
    NamesExtractor,
    DatesExtractor,
    MoneyExtractor,
    AddrExtractor,

    Doc
)
#from natasha.markup import show_markup, show_json
segmenter = Segmenter()
morph_vocab = MorphVocab()

emb = NewsEmbedding()
morph_tagger = NewsMorphTagger(emb)
syntax_parser = NewsSyntaxParser(emb)
ner_tagger = NewsNERTagger(emb)

names_extractor = NamesExtractor(morph_vocab)
dates_extractor = DatesExtractor(morph_vocab)
money_extractor = MoneyExtractor(morph_vocab)
addr_extractor = AddrExtractor(morph_vocab)
for line in df['Адрес объекта'].head(1):
    display(addr_extractor.find(line))
```

Результат кода выше отражен на скриншоте, теперь мне надо записать распарсенный адрес в одну строку, то есть 123456, г Москва, улица Марьинский парк ,д.21,кор.2

Пробывала так:

```
    listik = []
str_listik = []
for line in df['Адрес объекта'].head(100):
    
    #display(addr_extractor.find(line).fact.parts)
        #print(addr_extractor.find(line).fact.parts)    
# for match in parser.findall(addr_extractor.find(line).fact.parts):
#               print([_.value for _ in match.tokens]) 
    for index, paramValue in enumerate(addr_extractor.find(line).fact.parts):
        p=paramValue
        i = index
        if p.type=='индекс':
            listik.append( p.value)
        if p.type=='город':
            listik.append( p.value)
        if p.type=='улица':
            listik.append( p.value)
        if p.type=='дом':
            listik.append( p.value + ',')
        if  p.type=='корпус':
            listik.append(p.type + p.value + ',')
            
str_listik.append(' '.join(map(str,listik)))

print(str_listik)
```

В итоге получается одна строка с набором адресов, помогите получить разные строки.( отдельно по каждому адресу)

Comment: код в текстовом виде, без скриншотов.

Comment: А что за тэг такой natasha?

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов есть такая библиотека для парсинга адресов

Comment: интересно, а есть библиотека ингеборг?

Comment: @strawdog спасибо поправила

Comment: @Jack_oS Match(
    start=6,
    stop=112,
    fact=Addr(
        parts=[AddrPart(
             value='109469',
             type='индекс'
         ),
         AddrPart(
             value='Москва',
             type='город'
         ),
         AddrPart(
             value='Марьинский Парк',
             type='улица'
         ),

Comment: @Jack_oS я скриншот добавила

Comment: Match - это панда, я про addr_extractor.find(line) спрашиваю... выведите в цикле print(type(addr_extractor.find(line)), addr_extractor.find(line)), если там словари - работайте как со словарями (КО)

Comment: @Jack_oS <class 'natasha.extractors.Match'> Match(start=6, stop=112, fact=Addr(parts=[AddrPart(value='109469', type='индекс'), AddrPart(value='Москва', type='город'), AddrPart(value='Марьинский Парк', type='улица'), AddrPart(value='21', type='дом'), AddrPart(value='Верхние Поля', type='улица'), AddrPart(value='Марьинский парк', type='улица'), AddrPart(value='21', type='дом'), AddrPart(value='2', type='корпус')]))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инициализацию/очистку `listik = []` перенесите внутрь первого цикла (иначе в него будут собираться части всех адресов), а для строки `str_listik.append(' '.join(map(str,listik)))` добавьте отступ, чтобы она была внутри цикла (иначе в список `str_listik` попадает только последнее состояние списка `listik`).

```
str_listik = []

for line in df['Адрес объекта'].head(100):
    listik = []
    for index, paramValue in enumerate(addr_extractor.find(line).fact.parts):
        p=paramValue
        i = index
        if p.type=='индекс':
            listik.append( p.value)
        if p.type=='город':
            listik.append( p.value)
        if p.type=='улица':
            listik.append( p.value)
        if p.type=='дом':
            listik.append( p.value + ',')
        if  p.type=='корпус':
            listik.append(p.type + p.value + ',')
            
    str_listik.append(' '.join(map(str,listik)))

print(str_listik)
```